# g++ and operator << when changing value during evaluation gives unintentional result

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

Here's some simple code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool func(char* m)
{
    *m = '4';
    return true;
}

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char c1 = '3';
    cout  << "a" << c1 << func(&c1) << c1 << "b" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

when compile this with g++ -O0 (4.7.2), output is a413b, for -O2, output is a414b.
for clang++ 3.2, output is a314b.

Did I do anything undefined for c++ in this part of code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: not a dupe of that. There are plenty of sequence points.

Comment: It is generally a good idea to not mix computations and output. Compute all the values you need and then produce your output.

Comment: @BoPersson Or do the output of different values in different statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the order of evaluation of `func(&c1)` and the two `c1` is unspecified.

This means that the three expressions can be evaluated in any order, resulting in any of the following outputs:

```
a313b
a314b
a413b
a414b
```

See [function parameter evaluation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566187/function-parameter-evaluation-order)

Comment: Isn't it technically unspecified not undefined?

Answer (score 5):

We'll shorten your example a bit to wrap our heads around it. Let's take the code:

```
char func(char* m) { *m = '4'; return *m; }

int main() {
    char c = '1';
    cout << c << func(&c);

}
```

The cout line gets transformed like this:

```
operator<<(operator<<(cout, c), func(&c))
```

Because function arguments can be evaluated in any order, the compiler can choose to evaluate the inner `operator<<(cout, c)` first, or `func(&c)` first. Depending on which one is evaulated first, you will either get:

```
`14`
```

or

```
`44`
```