# C++ reference on static variable

Tags: c++, reference, static

I just find out that this little piece of C++ code doesn't give me the same result with clang++ and with g++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const string& createString(char c) {
    static string s;
    s="";
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    s+=c;
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    cout << createString('a') << ' ' << createString('z') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With clang++ it writes:

> aaaaaaaaaa zzzzzzzzzz

like I want it to be, but with g++ it writes:

> aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa

Why is it so? Is the g++ implementation standard compliant?
And what should I do if I want a function to return a temporary "big" type by reference like here to avoid useless copy?

Comment: Why is your `string` `static` in the first place?!

Comment: For other readers, Note that the string is being returned by reference.

Comment: to be return by reference, it must be, no ?

Comment: Return the "big" string by value.  In release mode, almost any compiler will apply the Return Value Optimization and it won't be copied at all.  Or if you use a C++11 compiler, it will be moved instead of copied if the RVO cannot be applied.

Comment: Your function should return "return std::string(c, 10);" without all those other lines and especially without the static.

Comment: @nvoigt Your constructor arguments are not in the correct order.

Comment: You are right... copied it from the next tab and still got it wrong... "return std::string(10,c);"

Comment: Is your "big" type not move-constructable?  If it has a fast move-constructor, just return an xvalue by value.  :)

Comment: That's weird, in clang++ it prints `aaaaa aaaaa` -- http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=84def7c0630a823fe48b1002a4c4260c-41475e255c735859f2b181fd0d057a6f

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> And what should I do if I want a function to return a temporary "big"
>   type by reference like here to avoid useless copy ?

It won't be. RVO and NRVO can trivially take care of this. In addition, move semantics. In short, there's nothing problematic about returning a `std::string` by value at all.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, both implementations are compliant. [The order of evaluation of function arguments is not specified.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566187/function-parameter-evaluation-order)

Therefore, `createString('a')` and `createString('z')` can be evaluated in any order. Furthermore, `createString('z')` can be evaluated before or after the result of `createString('a')` is written out.

Since the function is stateful, and returns the state by reference, both outputs are permissible, as is `zzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzz`.

Finally, it is worth noting that having `static` state would be a major headache in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: It isn't the order of `createString('a')` and `createString('z')`, but rather their relative order with the `<<` operators that causes the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Indeed. The compiler is allowed to generate both calls to `createString()` before any calls to `operator<<()` (as g++ is apparently doing), or to intersperse them (as clang++ is doing.) So it's the relative order of all of these function calls that matters.

Comment: @Yakk, but that order isn't specified either. A result of `aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa` or `zzzzzzzzzz aaaaaaaaaa` would be just as valid.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't think `zzzzzzzzzz aaaaaaaaaa` is a legal output.  `createString('z')` certainly can run before `createString('a')`, but `createString('a')` must still run before the first `operator<<`. So if 'z' runs first then the output must be `aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa` and if 'a' runs first then the output can be either `aaaaaaaaaa zzzzzzzzzz` or `zzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzz`.

Comment: @bames53 of course you're right, I wasn't thinking it through enough.

Answer (score 2):

> And what should I do if I want a function to return a temporary "big" type by reference like here to avoid useless copy ?

Call it only once per expression.  For example, this will work fine:

```
std::cout << createString('a') << ' ';
std::cout << createString('z') << std::endl;
```