# Unable to understand the output of C progaram

Tags: c, output

My code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c='8';
    int d=8;
    printf("%d %d %d",d,d+=c>='0'&&c<='9',c++);
    return(0);
}
```

The output of this question is : 9 9 56.
I'm unable to understand this.
Please somebody help me and please explain me the output.
Thanks.

Comment: char `8` is `56` in decimal.  The other part is well handled by the question mentioned above.

Comment: Are you competing in a code obfuscation competition or trying to understand orders of operation?

Comment: Check slide 159, 189, 196, 197 of http://www.pvv.org/~oma/DeepC_slides_oct2011.pdf :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically printf reads the argument from right to left so  the first print would be of

```
 " printf("%d %d %d",d,d+=c>='0'&&c<='9',c++);  " 

 -  1st output  = c++ -> which is nothing but ascii value of '8' = 56 
   and then c is incremented by 1 . 

 - next is the d -> it boils down to d = d + if(c>='0'&&c<='9') ... 
     so d = d+1  so  9 here

 - next d again so it is again  Hope it is clear !
```

Comment: -1 , *printf reads the argument from right to left* is not correct, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9566538/2327831

Comment: Ok , I correct my statment . The output may vary from compiler to compiler . But in this specific scenario it was reading from right-to-left and hence we could see this behavior . On other day in another compiler it might be completely different .

Answer (score 5):

You are observing undefined behaviour. `d` is passed as an argument twice, and once with side effects. If done in sequence your code should be equivalent to

```
char c='8';
int d=8;
printf("%d",d);

d+= (c>='0)' && (c<='9');
printf(" %d", d);
printf(" %d",c);
c++;
```

But since it is undefined in what order the arguments are computed when passing them with side effects to a function you are seeing here:

```
char c='8';
int d=8;

d+= (c>='0)' && (c<='9');
printf("%d",d);
printf(" %d", d);
printf(" %d",c);
c++;
```

Comment: Is it undefined? The [list of sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575350/sequence-points-in-c) seems to suggest arguments are evaluated *before* the function call.

Comment: @Gaminic the order in which parameters evaluated isn't defined

Comment: Yes, but in this case, the "odd print" is the regular 'd'. Given that all parameters are evaluated before the actual call, the value of 'd' is entirely predictable/defined, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the first thing you have to  know is, a char is stored in the memory as [Ascii Table](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/?kw=string). So in the memory the `char c` will have a integer value of '8'. From the table we know that the integer value of '8' is 56. According to the table we'll get:

'8': 56

'0': 48

'9': 57

So let's get started.

`c++`: It is a statement which adds c by one and return the value of current c.

Example:

```
int a,c;
c=1;
a=c++;
printf("a=%d,c=%d",a,c);
```

The result of this code is "a=1,c=2"

so `%d` of c++ is still 56.

`d+=c>'0'&&c<='9'`: According to C's priority this statement will be like:

`d+=(c>'0'&&c<='9')`

So let's start with `c>'0'&&c<='9'` first. It is a condition statement. Is c's Ascii value great or equal to 0's Ascii value AND less or equal to 9's Ascii value?( Notice c's Ascii is 56 or 57 now because the evaluation order of `printf` is undefined. So it will be 56 if this statement is evaluated before `c++` or 57 if after `c++`. But both way, `c<='9'` is true ) YES. So the statement is true. In C the TRUE is 1.

So `d+=c>'0'&&c<='9'` will be `d+=1` which means d=d+1. So `%d` of d is 9.

So the result is "9 9 56"

Comment: "the printf is be evaluated from right to left": the order in which parameters evaluated isn't defined http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c

Comment: @Deepthought didn't notice that. I'll change my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain this : "c++: It means add c and 1 and store the result in a temp variable. After this statement copy the result form the temp value to c. So inside the current statement, the c value remain unchanged. so %d of c++ is still 56."

Comment: @GaurangTandon sorry my first explaination is not accurate. the temp variable will store the current value of c and c is added by one. But the temp value will be the return value of the `++` statement. This is the true thing behind screen. I have changed my answer. Sorry

Comment: @zyc , it's okay :-). I got the answer