# std::cout with multi changing variables

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Assuming this code

```
int main(){
    int i=0, j=0;

    cout << i << " " << f1(&i,&j) << " " << j << endl;

    cout << i << " " << j << endl;
}

int f1(int *i, int *j){
    *i = 20;
    *j = 30;

    return 10;
}
```

The result is

```
20 10 0
20 30
```

I am puzzled as to why j would be 0 while i correctly shows 20

EDIT: I have read up on the sequence point but I am still unsure of how to explain this. Should I assume j is evaluated first before f1 is evaluated hence j is 0 and i is 20?

Comment: Probably not a dupe, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566187/function-parameter-evaluation-order

Comment: [Also related (if not a duplicate)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Answer (score 2):

Here the thing:

```
cout << i << " " << f1(&i,&j) << " " << j << endl;
```

if you consider from right to left evaluation, `j` was initially `0` and printed. Then, `f1` get called and `j` value is changed to `30`.
But this order of evaluation is unpredictable

Comment: so it means the evaluation order depend entirely on compiler?