# The difference when use function in or out of printf?

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int thi(int x, int *y) {
    x=*y; 
    *y=2*x; 
    return x+*y;
}

int main () {
    int x=1, y=2; 
    printf("%d, %d, %d", thi(y, &x), x, y);
}
```

I'm wondering that why the result is 3 1 2. This must be 3 2 2 right?

Comment: No, it is unspecified ([why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9566187/335858)).

Comment: try using `int a=1, b=2;` to simplify debugging, and use different values to help you understand what's actually  going on

Answer (score -1):

No the output `3 1 2` is correct. You would have execute the function before the `printf` if you want the changes to be made.

Try:

```
int main () {
    int a=1, b=2;
    int temp = thi(b,&a);
    printf("%d, %d, %d", temp, a, b);
}
```