# confused how printf works when printing a function directly

Tags: c, unit-testing, printf

I created a small program to convert temperature units from C° to F.
the char unit needs to be reversed 'C' to 'F' and vice versa. in order to do so, I'm modifying the address of `char unit` directly in my function `temp`.
now I'm a bit confused about how printf works when printing a function directly. precisely at this line:

`printf("%.1lf %c", temp(input, &unit), unit);`

my problem is that the `printf` is printing my unmodified `unit` even though my function already modified the value of `char unit`: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk623.png) / [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq7BR.png)

I can solve this by storing the function value into a double variable and printing it:

```
result = temp(input, &unit);
printf("%.1lf %c", result, unit);
```

could someone explain to me where my above logic is wrong
`printf("%.1lf %c", temp(input, &unit), unit);` It seems to me that printf is printing the value of my function first and then the `unit`. the `unit` value is being modified inside the function so I don't understand why it wasn't modified.

thanks a lot for your time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double temp(int, char *);

int main(void) {
    int input = 0;
    char unit = 'a';
    double result = 0.0;
    printf("Temperature unit:");
    scanf("%d %c", &input, &unit);
    printf("%.1lf %c", temp(input, &unit), unit);
}

double temp(int temp, char * unit) {
    double output = 0.0;
    
    //convert to C°
    if (*unit == 'F') {
        output = (((double)temp - 32) * 5 / 9);
        *unit = 'C';
    }
    else if (*unit == 'C') {
        output = (double)temp * 9 / 5 + 32;
        *unit = 'F';
    }
    else {
        printf("wrong unit");
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%.1lf %c", temp(input, &unit), unit);` it is an undefined behaviour as the function called changes (side effect) the second parameter. In such a situation you cant do it this way.

you need to:

```
printf("%.1lf ", temp(input, &unit));
printf("%c", unit);
```

or

```
double temperature = temp(input, &unit);
printf("%.1lf %c", temperature, unit);
```

Comment: @FatSumo https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/08/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/

Comment: This is not undefined behavior. It is indeterminate. The function call `temp(input, &unit)` may be evaluated before or after the `unit` argument, but there will be a sequence point before the function call and after its `return`. So the evaluation of the `unit` argument and the change to it in `temp` are indeterminately sequenced but not unsequenced.

Comment: I started programing about 3 months ago, would you have something I could read about concerning this behavior? thanks a lot

Comment: @FatSumo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566187/function-parameter-evaluation-order. Basically in C, within a construct that is a single statement, if some things do not have a *specific* cause-and-effect relation then they can be evaluated in any order, and the order can change for even the single statement from time to time.

Comment: If you want to be sure about the order of side effects, you need to split them into separate statements.

Answer (score 0):

> where my above logic is wrong (?)

Error is in "even though my function already modified the value of char unit".

The order of *evaluation* of arguments `temp(input, &unit)` and `unit` given to `printf("%.1lf %c", temp(input, &unit), unit);` is not defined.

`unit` may be evaluated before `temp(input, &unit)` or the other way around.